# Assigning the correct repository in a class with multiple repositories with the same base type using Ninject

Tags: c#, ioc-container, ninject

### Example

As an example of what I'm talking about let's say I have 2 repositories:

```
SubordinateRepository : IRepository<User> 
{
    // ...
}
```

Subordinate repository is used for getting the subordinates of a user.

---

```
DelegateRepository : IRepository<User> 
{
    // ...
}
```

Delegate repository is used for getting any other users that a given user has assigned as a delegate.

---

In my User class I have:

```
public class User
{
    public User(IRepository<User> subordinateRepo, IRepository<User> delegateRepo)
    {
        _subordianteRepository = subordinateRepo;
        _delegateRespository = delegateRepo;
    }

    private IRepository<User> _subordianteRepository;
    private IRepository<User> _delegateRespository;
}
```

---

### Question

How can I set up the bindings, using Ninject, so that each abstract `IRepository<User>` is assigned to the proper concrete repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the variety of examples of options on the [Contextual Binding section in the wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)

Comment: Thanks Ruben, it looks like the Named binding will work for me this go round.